# How to display linebreak

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a string containing line breaks however when I display them, the line breaks do not appear. All text is placed next to eachother.
I have tried `"\n"`,i have used

`<pre>`

but this did not help This is the string:

```
this.zorgdomein = ('some text \n some text');
```

and then in HTML I simply use

```
{{this.zorgdomein}}
```

Current result:

```
some text some text
```

expected result:

```
some text
some text
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ammwh9. Note that `this`is redundant in angular expressions. If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem in a stackblitz.

Comment: if you satisfying with my answer please vote up ☻

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like This

**.TS**

```
zorgdomein: string;

constructor() {
  this.zorgdomein = ('some text \n some text');
}
```

**.Html**

with `pre` tag

```
{{ this.zorgdomein }}
```

You Can Preview or Edit Code [Here On StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfdkfu)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Property Binding**

```
<div [innerHTML]="zorgdomein"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax:

`this.zorgdomein = 'some text \n some text';` // nobrackets here

`<div [innerHTML]="zorgdomein"></div>`